# Having issues with custom cronjob script within WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, azure-webjobs

I am having an issue within a custom cron script that I have located within a custom plugin I created for my WordPress site. I can execute the cron script via a web browser with no issues, however, when it is executed via the cron job, it continually errors out and says it can not connect to the database.

My cron script is located in my plugin folder:

```
/home/site/wwwroot/wp-content/plugins/PLUGIN/cron.php
```

Within the script I have have the following line:

```
require_once('includes/config.php');
```

In my `/includes/config.php` file I have it set up to include the wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'ABSPATH', dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))))) . '/' );
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php');
```

I have tried a few different ways to call the cron.php script but it appears that each time I still get the database connection error when running only from the cron tasks.

Any thoughts on how to get this to execute correctly?

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention, this is what is executed in my cron job:

```
cd D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-content\plugins\PLUGIN\
php -f cron.php
```

Comment: did you try printing ABSPATH variable to sure it point to right directory?

Comment: @bob_1982 - Yes, I thought of that too, and everything is correct. After some more digging, it looks like my Azure host stores the connection string for the database in a $_SERVER variable and when the cron job is ran, that variable does not seem to be present. Looking into alternatives.....

Comment: why are you using$_SERVER variable as if you include wp-config.php then you have direct access to DB_PASSWORD etc.likedefine('DB_NAME', 'database_name_here');

 /** MySQL database username */
 define('DB_USER', 'username_here');

      /** MySQL database password */
     define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here');

     /** MySQL hostname */
     define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

Comment: @bob_1982 Unfortunately, that is the way Azure is set up with their MySQL in app service.

Comment: oh ok .did you find the solution then?

Comment: Not exactly. I got it work within the Azure WebJobs using a file_get_contents and the url, however, this is not the preferable approach. Hoping a service ticket to MSFT can unearth some other options.

Answer (score 0):

If it works via the browser, you can run the cron with a wget.

```
wget https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/PLUGIN/cron.php
```